# Unordered and ordered lists are not aligning to the column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a 3 column webpage. My bullets for the unordered and ordered lists are not aligning with the corresponding text in the column. Also, for my middle column the text is scrunched together. How do I space the paragraphs apart?

```css
* {
  font-family: Melvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
  background-color: #6B6A67;
}
#container {
  width: 920px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: auto;
  /*will center your page*/
  margin-right: auto;
  /*will center your page*/
}
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
/*To style an ID within an ID under it use the parent ID--start with header then call the ID you want to select*/

#container #header {
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
}
#container #navigation {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  color: white;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #ADA9A0;
}
#container #content {
  background-color: #D9D5CE;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  /*To add empty space to bottom of the element*/
}
#container #content #sidebar1 {
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#container #content #column1 {
  background-color: white;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#container #content #sidebar2 {
  background-color: #ADA9A0;
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
  min-height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}
#container #footer {
  padding-top: 1px;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
.CR {
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
}
.Instructor h4 {
  text-align: right;
  position: fixed right;
}
/*NAV LINKS - add an "a" to style items under the ID'S*/

#container #navigation a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  /*gets rid of the underlining effect*/
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 6px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
/*To add a hover put a:hover*/

#container #navigation a:hover {
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}
#container #content #left {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="HTML.CSS.css" />

  <title>My Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
      <h1> CIS 2336- Internet Applications </h1>
      <h2> DeVoll </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="navigation">
      <a href="http://tdevoll16f.heyuhnem.com/index1.html/CIS 2336/My Portfolio/MyPage1.html">Home</a>
      <a href="#">HTML/CSS</a>
      <a href="#">PHP</a> 
    </div>
    <div id="content">

      <div id="sidebar1">
        <h4> Instuctor: Natalia Fofanova </h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Lectures</li>
          <li>Syllabus</li>
          <li>Helpful Videos</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div id="column1">
        <h2> HTML and CSS </h2>
        <p>HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) and CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) are two of the core technologies for bulding a website.
          <p>

            <p>HTML provides a structure for the page by using "Hypertext" which refers to the hyperlinks that an HTML page may contain. Also, "Markup language" refers to the way tags are used to define the page layout and elements within the page.</p>
            <p>CSS provides the visual layout of web pages. They can be used to define text styles, table sizes, and other aspects of Web pages that previously could only be defined in a page's HTML. CSS helps Web developers create a uniform look across
              several pages of a Web site. Instead of defining the style of each table and each block of text within a page's HTML, commonly used styles need to be defined only once in a CSS document.</p>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="sidebar2">
        <h4> Homework and Projects </h4>
        <ul>
          <li>Module 1</li>
          <li>Module 2</li>
          <li>Module 3</li>
          <li>Welcome Button</li>
          <li>2-column Webpage</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>

    <footer>
      <div id="footer">
        <div class="CR">
          <h4> Copyright 2016 </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="Instructor">
          <a href="http://heyuhnem.com/"><h4>Copyright Natalie Fofanova </h4> </a>
        </div>

    </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare a line-height to the 2nd section.

Example

```
#second p {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
p{
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Add this to your CSS hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

As your code should change like the below code:

```
#content ul{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:block;
}
#content ul li {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style-type:none;/* if you really wants bullets remove this line*/
}
* {
  font-family: Melvetica;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
body {
   background-color: #6B6A67;
   line-height:20px;
}
#column1 p{padding:4px;}
.clearfix{clear:both;}
```

To change your min-height should be  min-height: 320px; instead of 300px.

You want to more clarity in this question. please tell me we will suggest some more points.

i will update your code jsfiddle.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/balanuidev/7pzbc4h3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
p{
padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
```

just padding down would make sure space between all paragraph

Comment: There is no `padding-down` in CSS... You mean `pasding-bottom`?

Comment: thnx for for pointing out the mistake!
i meant padding: 0 0 10px 0;